# UPS Compatibility with Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, power-management, ups

I'm looking into getting battery backup unit to protect my Ubuntu server. How can I find out if it is compatible with Ubuntu (11.04)?

Ideally I'd like to be able to tell the server when there is a power outage so the server can shutdown. I know most of them come with software that works with Windows, but haven't seen any that mention Linux or Ubuntu.

Are there any good resources for setting up UPS's with Ubuntu? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the most popular UPS companies is [APC](http://www.apc.com).

To monitor and powerdown my server I have been using **apcupsd** which has lots of options and a comprehensive [userguide](http://www.apcupsd.com/manual/manual.html) for setting it up. It has worked well with my [APC Smart-UPS 700VA](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SU700IBX120) for many years.

You may find that you need to spend a bit more to get a UPS unit that has a serial/usb cable to communicate power status with the server.

Comment: Rising up this, i'd say the same answer ;-)

Comment: thanks for your answer! it seems a lot of UPS devices have serial ports to communicate. since my server doesn't have a serial port, can i just use a generic serial->usb cable, or does converting get tricky?

Comment: @Evan I don't see any problems with using an adapter.

Comment: How about Forza? Any software for it?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Network UPS Tools (NUT)](https://networkupstools.org/index.html) - an open-source library of software and drivers which support a vast variety of UPS devices.

While much of the support in this project relies on unofficial / reverse-engineered compatibility, it seems to be much simpler to install and configure rather than using the proprietary software and drivers provided by the OEM.

The biggest benefit to NUT is that many OEM's force you to purchase a very expensive UPS just to get a device having compatibility with their management software on Linux. Because of this, most entry-level devices will only communicate with the watered-down Windows software they provide. NUT provides this capability to Linux users without needing the official software.

APC and CyberPower are two of the most popular hardware OEMs for UPS. If you browse NUT's website, you'll see a list of all compatible OEMs and models. From what I've seen, many people have reported success with NUT even on models not listed on the website.

**One last important thing:** Make sure the UPS supports USB (communication, not just charging) or Ethernet. Many entry-level devices may have no means of communication, others will use connections less common (RS-232) in consumer products, and some will require you to purchase a network card to add Ethernet.