# UPS recommendations for a desktop computer

Tags: hardware, ups

My question is related to [UPS Compatibility with Ubuntu Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44170/ups-compatibility-with-ubuntu-server) , but might be different.

I am currently running the desktop version of Ubuntu 11.10 on my desktop computer. I run it continuously as I use it for most of my studies, and also as use as an alarm clock in addition to my backup. My floor in our university dorm this year seems to have been having a problem with brief power outages, which I don't believe is good for my hard drives (besides being annoying). As such, I'm finally considering getting a UPS.

My requirements are nothing fancy: I just need something that is easy to set up and will last just long enough for me to do a proper shutdown in the event of a power outage, or continue running as normal if the outage only lasts a minute or two. In my case, I'd consider cheaper to be better.

The question I mentioned earlier had an [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44170/ups-compatibility-with-ubuntu-server/44174#44174) recommending the APC brand for a server setup. Is this what I should look for in my case, or would there be something more appropriate? At any rate, I'll probably be getting one from my parents when they shop this weekend from a brick-and-mortar Micro Center store, so it'd be great if I had some recommendations to give them before they go out and a clueless/commissioned sales associate tells them what to buy for a Windows machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a very cheap (~30€) revolt UPS for my workstation at work; I use nut to shut down the machine in case of an outage.

It is nothing fancy, but it's proven to work.

Here is my ups.conf containing all the details:

```
[revolt]
    driver = genericups
    upstype = 4
    port = /dev/ttyS0
    pollinterval=3
    desc = Revolt USV 500VA
    mfr=ReVolt
    model=PE7132
    serial = 07380274232
```

(Edit: That said, if your parents are able and willing to buy APC, than by all means get one of those :-) )

Comment: Well, went ahead and got an APC UPS. I can't set it up right away because I'm a bit busy at the moment, but if I need help setting it up I might ask in a separate question.